# C++ Decompressing a file, then compressing the decompressed data does not give the same file as a result

Tags: c++, compression, zlib

I'm using ZLib along with header files from https://github.com/mapbox/gzip-hpp to handle gzip files.

I have been trying for days now. I have a file say "abc," and as I decompress it, I compress it back and save the compressed result in another file "xyz." Now, theoretically, data of "abc" should be equal to "xyz," but that's not the case. As I compare, both the files are different. I'm using fstream to read/write files with binary flags. I've tried different compression levels as well, but failed. I also checked the decompressed data and it stands accurate. My only trouble is compressing it back, which yields different results from original.

Comment: Result of compresson will depend on compression setting (for example, window size), so it need not be same.

Comment: Does your program produce the same file if you run it twice and save the result to a different name?

Comment: The library used for compression probably also influences the result

Comment: I've tried a  lot of different settings, Mike, and none helped. Yes, I made it produce 10 different files, but the results were same, Retired Ninja. Alam, I tried 3 different libraries, but same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to expect nor any need to be able to reconstruct the same compressed data. What is guaranteed for lossless compression is that x -> compress -> decompress -> y will result in y being exactly the same as x. There is no guarantee for p -> decompress -> compress -> q that q is the same as p, or similar to p, or even the same length as p.

The difference can vary due to different compression software, a different version of the same compression software, or different compression settings for the same version.

The zlib and gzip compressors, while written by the same person, will generally produce different compressed data regardless of the settings you select. They have different approaches internally for when they decide to emit a deflate block.

Comment: I'm making a game save modifier and to load the save file back into the game it needs to have a certain gzip format and that I'm not able to figure out. I hope this clears the "nor any need to be able to reconstruct the same compressed data" part.

Comment: No, that doesn’t clear it up. If you need exactly the same gzip stream, then use the original. If you are modifying the contents of the gzip stream, then it cannot be the same.

Comment: What do you mean "If you need exactly the same gzip stream, then use the original"? And I've told clearly I haven't modified anything.

Comment: I mean use file "abc", not file "xyz". I mean don't decompress and recompress. Just use "abc".

Comment: Then I won't be able to modify it. That's the problem.

Comment: You are not making any sense. You want the compressed data to be exactly the same, _and_ you want to modify the uncompressed data? If you modify the uncompressed data, the compressed data cannot be the same.

Comment: Its either I'm bad at explaining, or you're worse at understanding. Here's the thing - the game will only recognize a certain type of GZip format. But what I made can't even produce the same file as original, let alone be a working modified file. Is that clear enough?

Comment: Then your problem has absolutely nothing to do with reproducing the same compressed data. You need to figure out what "a certain type" means exactly. There is only one gzip format, and it is interoperable across all compliant implementations. Can you provide an example of such a gzip file? Perhaps there is extra data, a needed file name, or particular attributes in the gzip _header_ that the application is looking for.

Comment: Anywhere we can talk privately about this, sir? I need to show you some files and a program and a few more things which are impossible to be shown here. Once we get onto a conclusion we can post the required stuff here. Can it go this way?

Comment: Sorry, no. You will need to abstract your problem as needed to be able to post it here.

Comment: I figured it out. The file is compressed using a Salt. Without salting the target program will not accept the file. Thanks to all who commented down here.

Comment: @SAHILSINGHDHESI Then you should write an answer to your own question and accept it.